# Warning Message after Postmap Header_Checks with Postfix

Tags: linux, email, postfix, email-server, ubuntu-12.04

I'm using postfix-pcre on my Ubuntu Server.
If I test my header_checks configuration with the following command

`postmap -q 'To: "Markus Schlei" <yylyclw@test.de>' regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks`

I get the following warning message:

> postmap: warning: regexp map /etc/postfix/header_checks, line 36: Invalid preceding regular expression.

Also it's not reject my test. On Line 36 I got this code:

`/^To:.*\@(?!(gmail\.com)).*/ REJECT Test-Nr-1`

I want to reject all messages which not match with **gmail.com**

Edit 1: I found out that, if I remove the "(**?!**(..)" the warning message gone away, but it do the inverse what I want.

Comment: Be careful about enforcing policy in anything but a rfc5322-aware parser: Address headers can contain group names and comments. What you are matching here is not just not necessarily where the message is delivered (envelope != headers), but also possibly not part of what would be displayed in a typical mail client.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that there is POSIX regular expression and PCRE regular expression.

You are using a **negative lookahead** (`?!`) with a *regexp* table. This type of regular expression is only supported by PCRE regex tables.

> To find out what types of lookup tables your Postfix system supports
> use the "postconf -m" command.

If pcre is listed then just switch to pcre tables instead of regexp tables. If not, you have to install *postfix-pcre*.

Comment: PCRE is listed.

I'm stuck in my head about how to switch from regexp table to pcre.
I was thinking every time already use a pcre table.

On my main.cf file I put this param:

`header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks`

Comment: Yes, using `pcre:` instead of `regexp:` should work just fine.